# Scrolling Behavior in Terminal

Tags: terminal, macos

Until recently, when I scrolled in my terminal, it scrolled through the history. However, recently that behavior changed and now it scrolls through the *command* history.

Where is the setting to change it back?

Comment: How do you scroll?

Comment: Two fingers on the trackpad.

Comment: Do you use the shell inside some other program like tmux or screen? By default Terminal sends input to the tty if the alternate screen is active, to cause programs like editors and pagers to scroll in response to scroll gestures. Those programs select the alternate screen.

Comment: Nope. I was using the default terminal app.

Comment: I have the same issue.  If you've found an answer, please let me know!

Comment: One thing I did discover is that holding the shift key while scrolling seems to get it to scroll as desired.

Comment: and finally, I am using zsh as my default shell.  Are you using a non-standard shell as well?  Maybe that explains the lack of lots of google results for this.

https://www.reddit.com/r/osx/comments/397uep/changes_to_bash_sessions_and_terminal_in_el/